# MySQL - How to merge rows based on user id and make SUM

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have written following MySQL select query:

```
SELECT cs.id, cs.campaign_id, cs.instagram_id, cs.media_id, cs.has_tag, cs.comments_count, cs.likes_count, DATE(cs.created_date) AS created_date, sl.username, (cs.comments_count + cs.likes_count) AS total_comments_likes
FROM campaign_statistic AS cs 
LEFT JOIN social_login AS sl ON sl.social_id = cs.instagram_id
WHERE instagram_id IN (481959735, 12095962) 
AND has_tag = 'sometag' 
ORDER BY created_date ASC
```

And getting this result:

[image]

Now you can see there are three entry from `2015-12-10`:

```
id  campaign_id     instagram_id    media_id                         has_tag     comments_count     likes_count     created_date    username    total_comments_likes
66  50              481959735       1110926795500814980_481959735    sometag     1                  51              2015-12-10      myname      52
74  50              12095962        1102652300222991882_12095962     sometag     0                  16              2015-12-10      myname      16
77  50              481959735       1096415071007540220_481959735    sometag     0                  18              2015-12-10      myname      18
```

You can see `481959735` instagram id has two records for that day(2015-12-10). Now I want SUM **comments_count & likes_count** of **481959735** and merge in on row.

I want this output:

```
id  campaign_id     instagram_id    media_id                         has_tag     comments_count     likes_count     created_date    username    total_comments_likes
66  50              481959735       1110926795500814980_481959735    sometag     1                  69              2015-12-10      myname      70
74  50              12095962        1102652300222991882_12095962     sometag     0                  16              2015-12-10      myname      16
```

Any idea how to do this with mysql query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

USE `Group By` clause and `SUM` function for SUM

Query will be

> SELECT cs.campaign_id, cs.instagram_id,Sum(cs.comments_count),
>   SUM(cs.likes_count),Sum(cs.comments_count) +SUM(cs.likes_count) AS
>   total_comments_likes FROM campaign_statistic AS cs  LEFT JOIN
>   social_login AS sl ON sl.social_id = cs.instagram_id WHERE
>   cs.instagram_id IN (481959735, 12095962)  AND has_tag = 'sometag' 
>   group by cs.campaign_id, cs.instagram_id ORDER BY created_date ASC

Answer (score 0):

You can sum() the needed fields. This works if you `group by cs.instagram_id`.

```
SELECT
  cs.id,
  cs.campaign_id,
  cs.instagram_id,
  cs.media_id,
  cs.has_tag,
  sum(cs.comments_count) as comments_count,
  sum(cs.likes_count) as likes_count,
  DATE(cs.created_date) AS created_date,
  sl.username,
  sum(cs.comments_count + cs.likes_count) AS total_comments_likes
FROM campaign_statistic AS cs 
LEFT JOIN social_login AS sl ON sl.social_id = cs.instagram_id
WHERE instagram_id IN (481959735, 12095962) 
AND has_tag = 'sometag' 
group by cs.instagram_id
ORDER BY created_date ASC
```

Comment: Getting this error: '
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.likes_count,
  DATE(cs.created_date) AS created_date,
  sl.username,
  sum(cs.c' at line 8 '

Comment: Edited, please try again.